# roslaunch + screen

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anybody had any luck in setting this up?
I don't know how to tell screen to launch different ros nodes in different screen-windows of the same screen-session.
I can do it manually, but i would ideally like to make it part of my boot script.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9099/roslaunch-+-screen/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-02-17**:
when you see an answer you like, mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can use "screen -X screen -U" in the launch-prefix attribute.
-X option sends a command to a running screen.

But I don't know how to set the "default" launch-prefix, you may need to
edit all the node tags like below:

---

Originally posted by [Ryohei Ueda](https://answers.ros.org/users/59/ryohei-ueda/) with karma: 317 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-17**:
Note, you can edit your previous answer to include this new information instead of posting a whole new answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

does "screen -U roslaunch ..." resolve your problem?

when you run "screen -U" in a screen-window, screen will make another screen-window in your screen-session
and run the command you specified.

it would be good to make an alias to "screen -U roslaunch" like below:

```
 $ alias slaunch="screen -U roslaunch"
 $ slaunch your_awesome_program.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Ryohei Ueda](https://answers.ros.org/users/59/ryohei-ueda/) with karma: 317 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on 2011-02-17**:
What I want is to launch different nodes in different screen windows. What you suggested will just lunch all the nodes specified in the launch file in one screen window.